How to resolve save as button in Pentaho server
When I connect to the Pentaho Server from the desktop PDI and try to use the save as button, I get an error asking me to contact the administrator, when I check the log I get this screenshot
As additional information, I use pentaho server 9.4 CE on a linux server and almost 600 scheduled jobs
The first time the error appeared, it was fixed by restarting the server, now the restart fixes it for a few minutes and then continues.
The last time it was fixed for a few minutes when the connection string was recreated, but now it occurs with all transformations that use TABLE INPUT as a step
